# Future returned by a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

I try to understand the concept of `future` and `promise` but have some issues to use them as return values from functions.

I came up with the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

std::future<int> func(int i);

class A{
public:
    A(std::promise<int> && prms, int i):thread_([&]{
        std::cout << "Thread created in A\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        prms.set_value(i*2);
        thread_.detach();
    }){std::cout << "Call constructor of A\n";}
    ~A(){std::cout << "Call A's Destructor\n";}

private:
std::thread thread_;
};

int main()
{
    auto a_inst = func(2);
    a_inst.wait();
    std::cout << a_inst.get() << std::endl;

}

std::future<int> func(int i){
    std::promise<int> prms;
    //std::future<int> ftr = prms.get_future();
    A A1(std::move(prms), i);
    return prms.get_future();
}
```

So `main` should create a future from the return value of `func`, wait for the future to be assigned and then print it.
But when I execute it, `A` is constructed and destructed without the thread being executed. Could someone guide me to the right direction?

**edit**

I added the vector containing the different `promises`. The thread doesn't directly process the `promise` but calls the `processQueue` function to do it. The class `A` object is created once and a unique_ptr reference is handed to the function where it's required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

class A{
public:
    int element_pointer = 0;
    A():thread_([&]() {
        std::cout << "Thread created in A\n";
        for(;;){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
            processQueue();
        }
        //local_promise.set_value(local_i*2);
    })
    {
        std::cout << "Call constructor of A\n";
    }

    ~A(){
        thread_.detach();
        std::cout << "Call A's Destructor\n";
    }

    void enq(std::promise<int> prms){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        local_prmses_.push_back(std::move(prms));
        std::cout << "Queue now holds " << local_prmses_.size() << " elements\n";
    }

private:
    std::thread thread_;
    std::mutex m;
    std::vector<std::promise<int>> local_prmses_;
    void processQueue(){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        std::cout << "execute processQueue()" << std::endl;
            if(element_pointer < local_prmses_.size()){
                for(element_pointer; element_pointer<local_prmses_.size(); element_pointer++){
                    local_prmses_[element_pointer].set_value(6);
                    std::cout << "Promise assigned\n";
                }

            } else {
                std::cout << "Nothing to process" << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

std::future<int> func(std::unique_ptr<A>& obj, int i);

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> obj = std::make_unique<A>();
    auto futr = func(obj, 9);
    //a_inst.wait();
    //std::cout << a_inst.get() << std::endl;
    for(;;){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        if(futr.valid()){
            std::cout << "Yepeee!\n";
            std::cout << "Result is " << futr.get() << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "waiting...\n";
    }
}

std::future<int> func(std::unique_ptr<A>& obj, int i){
    std::promise<int> prms;
    auto fut = prms.get_future();
    obj->enq(std::move(prms));
    return fut;
}
```

Comment: You might prefer to `join` thread instead of `detach`ing it to ensure it is finished.

Comment: passing by rvalue reference has ownership transfer semantic, which is not your case.

Comment: You have several issue with lifetime of your object and so some dangling reference.

Comment: Okay, I thought I achieve the same with the a_inst.wait() in my main. When I move the detach line above the set_value, I get the output, but the promise-future concept doesn't work.

Comment: `std::async` seems more appropriate

Comment: Hmmm but `std::async` would create a new thread right? I'd like to have one thread handling several promises, so in the end it will be a std::vector<A> and I don't wan't to create a new thread every time a create a new object.
So you say that promise is out of scope as soon as the thread is finished and therefore prms.get_future() doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do. You may look at thread pool if you want to reuse your thread instead of recreating them each time.

Comment: I create a vector of objects `std::vector<A>` of which each elements contains a promise, the objects are created upon a function call of a read function. So the promise returns what ever the actual read function returns when finished. Then a separate thread will process this vector, means calling the read function for every entry filling all the promises one after another.

Comment: "I don't wan't to create a new thread every time a create a new object" - so why do you have a member `std::thread`?

Comment: The new code in your edit is very badly broken, you can't push objects into a vector from one thread and read them in another thread without synchronisation.

Comment: I expected this synchronization to be part of the whole promise and future story, so if that doesn't work... how should I do it?

Comment: @Humpawumpa the promise and future story guards you when you make the result available. you dont need to worry when setting the value through the promise and when getting it through the future. but the vector class is not guarded in any way. and thats whats happening: one thread inserts. one reads. from the vector

Comment: And therefore the `std::mutex`, got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 problems:

1. You are destructing your thread object in `A` before the thread can get detached.
   You could for example detach the thread in the A destructor, so control flow will reach it before A is completly destructed.
2. The lambda in your thread object is working on the promise which is only alive in the `func` function scope. As soon as control flow leaves this scope, your promise get destructed and throws a broken promise exception. To prevent that, your lambda function should take ownership of the promise. If it takes ownership, you have to make sure to get the future before the ownership movement.

This leads to the following code (i just removed your errors. whether its a good design is another question ;-P):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

std::future<int> func(int i);

class A{
public:
    A(std::promise<int> prms, int i):thread_([local_promise = std::move(prms), local_i = i]() mutable {
        std::cout << "Thread created in A\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        local_promise.set_value(local_i*2);
    })
    {
        std::cout << "Call constructor of A\n";
    }

    ~A(){
        thread_.detach();
        std::cout << "Call A's Destructor\n";
    }

private:
std::thread thread_;
};


int main()
{
    auto a_inst = func(9);
    a_inst.wait();
    std::cout << a_inst.get() << std::endl;
}

std::future<int> func(int i){
    std::promise<int> prms;
    auto fut = prms.get_future();
    A A1(std::move(prms), i);
    return fut;
}
```

live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e2a3b982ad6e9fb

Comment: Okay thanks for that, it helped me alot. I went a step further in the direction I wanna go (with my vector of promises)... would you consider this a cleaner implementation now or am I still violating some design rules?

Comment: @Humpawumpa Unfortunately there are still errors and design flaws. To start with the errors: You have a race condition on your vector holding the promises. That means: the thread in A is processing the vector elements while the main thread inserts something into it. You should guard it with a std::mutex. Then you need a way to shut down your thread cleanly. You dont have a stop condition. Designflaws: No need for a unique pointer. just create a on the stack and pass it by reference to your `func` function. Dont detach the thread. let the loop finish and join the thread cleanly.

Comment: @Humpawumpa And you may want to remove processed promisses from the vector. consider switching to a std::queue if it fits your need (i guess it does). regarding your processing loop: i dont like the sleep. consider using a conditional_variable to signal that new work is rdy to process. by doing this you will stop waking your thread up even if no work is available and it allows you to wake the thread up when you want to exit your application (imagine you have 100 `A` objects and when doing a shutdown all wait for 200ms. thats bad

Comment: You're right with the mutex, I don't plan to shutdown the thread, it shall process the vector/queue as long as the application is running. Why is a smart pointer is this case a wrong approach? 
Can I remove elements from my vector before I can be sure the future has been called? Or is the promise not required anymore once its value is set?

Comment: @Humpawumpa then why not just shut it down with `A`? :-P Well you dont need a heap allocated object. its faster on the stack and easier to reason about. prefer the stack whenever possible. Yes, the promise and the future are pointing to the same shared state. The last one cleans up. If you have already stored the future, then the promise can leave the playground. Then the future will clean up after getting the value and beeing destructed. If you have no future attached, then yeah the result is lost. But there wasnt anyone interessted anyway mh?

Comment: Sorry I'm from VHDL/C and just diving into C++ right now so I've some issues to get my head up to speed.
Good point, join thread with destructor of A, makes sense and thanks for the clarification of the future and promise relation. So when promise is already assigned to the future, once the promise has a set value, it can be destroyed.

Comment: @Humpawumpa No problem ;-) I overlooked something: since the thread in `A` uses the vector in `A`, you HAVE TO shutdown the thread. otherwise it tries to access the vector, but the vector is gone with `A` already. Regarding the future/promise: yes. The last instance alive cleans up. So the shared state (under the hood) is held alive as long as a promise or a future is refering to it.